# Infopath code-signing certificate compatibility issue

Tags: infopath, certificate

I have an InfoPath form with C# code-behind that was originally developed in InfoPath Designer 2003, but has been republished in InfoPath Designer 2010 many times.

I am trying to update the code-signing certificate for this form from SHA1 to SHA2, and have acquired a new certificate from InCommon for this purpose, but the new certificate is not 'seen' in the Form Options | Security and Trust | Select Certificate dialog (while the original SHA1 cert IS still 'seen').

There are hints online that SHA2 certificates are not compatible with InfoPath 2003 forms (but no formal compatibilty matrix has been published, right?).

In my case, where the form has been republished dozens of times in Infopath Designer 2010, is it likely that this form doesn't support SHA2 certificates either?

If so, what can I do to resolve this issue, as my cybersecurity folks don't allow SHA1 certs to be used anymore...